# Filter results by date range Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, html, css, angular

I hope you can help me I am very new to **Angular Material**

I have a table with N results and I am trying to do a filter for a range of dates. I have a *select* with the options (1 day, 5 days, 1 week, 15 days), which are loaded with a variable

JS

```
vm.rangos=[
     {id:"1",name:'1 día',value:'1'},
     {id:"2",name:'5 días',value:'5'},
     {id:"3",name:'1 Semana',value:'7'},
     {id:"4",name:'15 días',value:'15'}
  ];
```

HTML

```
<div layout="row" flex="90" layout-align="start center">
    <label flex="25">Rango</label>
        <select flex="60" ng-model="vm.rangoSelected" placeholder="" ng-options="ran.name for ran  in vm.rangos" class="selectPersonalizado ">
        </select>
 </div>
```

And I honestly do not know how to do the function to perform the filter to show results from within the selected range

In this function I collect the value of the selected

```
function sendFilter(){
      var filterSend = "";
      switch(vm.filterSelected){

          case 'rango':
            filterSend = vm.rangoSelected.value;
          break;
          default:
            alert('no hecho');
          break;

      }
      vm.showLastMovements(filterSend);
  }
```

JSON

```
{
  "result": {
    "httpCode": 200,
    "httpMessage": "OK",
    "moreInformation": ""
  },
  "data": {
    "movements": [
      {
        "operationDate": "2017-01-18",
        "concept": "Decathlon",
        "amount": "-450.0",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "balance": "29150.0",
        "category": 1
      },
      {
        "operationDate": "2017-01-18",
        "concept": "Corte Ingles",
        "amount": "-259.0",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "balance": "34000.0",
        "category": 2
      },
      {
        "operationDate": "2017-01-15",
        "concept": "Carrefour",
        "amount": "348.0",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "balance": "12000.0",
        "category": 1
      },
      {
        "operationDate": "2017-01-01",
        "concept": "Corte Ingles",
        "amount": "-259.0",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "balance": "34000.0",
        "category": 2
      },
      {
        "operationDate": "2016-12-30",
        "concept": "Cortefiel",
        "amount": "348.0",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "balance": "12000.0",
        "category": 1
      }

    ]
  }
}
```

In this function whith an alert, show me the value of the select.

If you can help me or at least give some information to create this function to then make the call from the case to show the records of that selection I would appreciate it.

Thank you very much

Comment: what is the content that you are trying to filter with the range?

Comment: I have a list with several results (category, date, description, price) and with this filter I try to show depends what I select (1 day, 5 days, 1 week or 15 days) the lastest. Actually I'm working with JSON to show the list, you ask me this?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand, With the filter you want to filter the results according to the range. Do you want to compare the range selected against the Date of the results content?

Comment: I have a form with a select to do the filter. In a table, first of all show all the results and with this filter I'm trying to show the results between today and "one day ago or five days or a week or 15 days ago". I have explained myself better now?

Comment: yes!, could you please add the related info of the table to the post?

Comment: I put the **JSON** in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be your html:

```
<div layout="row" flex="90" layout-align="start center">
    <label flex="25">Rango</label>
        <select flex="60" ng-model="vm.rangoSelected" placeholder="" ng-options="ran.name for ran  in vm.rangos" class="selectPersonalizado ">
        </select>
 </div>
```

And let suppose that this is your table iteration through the data.movements list

```
  <tr md-row  ng-repeat="movement in data.movements | filter: customFilter">
    <td md-cell>{{movement}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Controller:

```
function customFilter(movement){
   var movementDate = new Date (movement.operationDate);
   var filterDate= new Date();
   filterDate.setDate(filterDate.getDate() - vm.rangoSelected.value) //In here you will have to transform the rangoSelected.value to days.
   return (movementDate.getTime() > filterDate.getTime()); //this will return true if the movement's date is bigger than your selected range.
}
```

Remember that getTime() returns the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01. That will help you to do the range calculations.